# Equals vs space ("-o=value" vs "-o value") in *nix command line programs - best practices?

Tags: shell, command-line

I see no pattern in command line programs that take

```
-o=value
```

versus

```
-o value
```

For double dash long options, I see a major preference to the equals notation but not for short options. Is there a reason or best practice?

Comment: When you say "command line program", do you mean shell scripts exclusively?  Or are you referring to any program written in any language that can be called from a Unix command line?  If your program is written in Python, for example, with any of the standard option parsing libraries, then (a) the use of `=` doesn't matter, and (b) you as the writer of the program can't even make it matter.  The option parser is in charge of that.

Comment: @dg99 Wait, are you saying that a Python program can't differentiate between `-a bc` and `-a=bc` on the command line?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the standard parser modules in Python don't care.  They'll parse the command line with or without the `=`.  You'd have to do extra work *after* the module does its parsing if you want to reject certain command-line syntax.  (The point being that the OP's notion of "best practices" for how to enter options on the command line is -- if it exists -- probably not a programmer issue; it would be a user issue.  I can't tell whether the OP is asking from the programmer or user perspective.)

Comment: There may be some benefit to using the `=` form, since both option name and option value are placed in the same command-line argument, whereas `-o value` is two separate command-line arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some Googling it seems most discussions of the evolution of command-line arguments couple the rise of the `=` sign to the rise of GNU-style long options.  I can't find a reference stating explicitly that it was *never* common practice to use `=` to separate short options from their arguments, but I also can't find any discussion of anyone doing that.

Some brief discussions ...

- [Art of Command Line Programming - Command Line Options](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch10s05.html) - see introduction
- [perl Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) - see "Command Line Options, an Introduction" section
- [Command-line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) - no discussion of history, but perhaps further clicking might unearth some